# Apache Jmeter issue- Non HTTP response message: Malformed IPv6 address at index 8:"TestURL"

Tags: jmeter

Facing below error as in HTTP Request Defaults I haven't provided any HTTP in the server name/IP-

> Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.URISyntaxException
>   Response message: Non HTTP response message: Malformed IPv6 address at
>   index 8:"TestURL"

Answer (score 4):

It normally happens when you put protocol into "Server Name or IP" field of the [HTTP Request Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) (or [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/http-request-defaults)) . You should not put anything but application under test hostname or IP address there.

[image: JMeter HTTP Request Design]

If you are parameterising the whole URL - use "Path" section instead.

[image: JMeter HTTP Request Path]

Actually I believe it would be much easier just to record your test using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder). See [Apache JMeter proxy Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) guide for more details.